# Question "voluntarily removed by its author" with an answer that was upvoted and marked as answer

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

This could possibly be a dupe (if it is, my apologies), though I haven't seen any questions in my searching that match the same situation.

I just noticed a loss of 25 rep on SO, and it looks like the updates from today are working because it appropriately showed me why in the rep breakdown that one of my answers was unupvoted and unaccepted (seemingly simultaneously).

[image]

I assumed at first that it was one of the older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607345/stop-timeouts-server-side/9608101#9608101)s that I had answered while it was in the process of being closed, but rather it looks like it was *voluntarily removed by its author*. I didn't think an author could delete a question that had upvoted answers on it? Is this something that changed in the rep shake up over the last couple of weeks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The owner removed the upvote and accept (presumably so he could delete the question, which he'd be unable to do with an upvoted answer attached).  The *reputation* behavior is correct here, though you can certainly argue that behavior by the user is unwarranted...feel free to open a question from that view here on meta for discussion (it may already exist).

Comment: Thanks. Will do (of course I'll search first).